# Kotlin Compiler: Bad performance in multi maven module project

Tags: kotlin, maven

We are in the process of migrating from Java to Kotlin.
In the process, we ran into a problem where even a single Kotlin file in a module noticeably slows down the compilation process for that module.

For demonstration purposes, we created a simple multi-Maven module that looks like this:

parent

- Module a
- Module b
- Module c

With 100 Java files and 0 Kotlin files in module a, the following result is obtained:

```
[INFO] a .................................................. SUCCESS [ 2.069 s ]
[INFO] b .................................................. SUCCESS [ 0.350 s]
[INFO] c .................................................. SUCCESS [ 0.118 s]
[INFO] Parent POM ......................................... SUCCESS [ 0.071 s].
```

Adding only 1 Kotlin file to module a results in the following:

```
[INFO] a .................................................. SUCCESS [ 4.757 s]
[INFO] b .................................................. SUCCESS [ 0.121 s]
[INFO] c .................................................. SUCCESS [ 0.104 s]
[INFO] Parent POM ......................................... SUCCESS [ 0.066 s]`
```

It does not seem to matter how many Kotlin files we add to the module. With 100 Kotlin files in the same module, the compile time increases to 5.582 seconds. The problem seems to be the call to the Kotlin compiler, which must be called for each module.

**Since we are dealing with a project that contains almost 600 Maven modules, this issue will drastically increase our CI time.**

Is there anything we can do about it?
Will the Kotlin 2.0 Compiler address this Issue?

Comment: Did you measure what happens with 100% Kotlin modules? You seem to be measuring "Java only" vs "Java+Kotlin", maybe a "Kotlin only" measurement would help.

Comment: First question: Which Maven version do you use? Which JDK version? Are you using the most recent versions of all plugins within your build? Are you building serial or parallel? etc.? Much more information is needed to even make an educated guess?...

Comment: @Joffrey 
With 100% Kotlin code compiling does not speed up. If i have only Kotlin code in Module "a" the compilation time is ~4.3s

Comment: @khmarbaise
Java: 11
Kotlin: 1.8
Maven: 3.8.2

My setup is as basic as it gets. A Projekt with 3 Modules that does not make use of parallell building, and only has the adds the kotlin compiler as plugin.

The problem also exists in our main projekt but for demonstration purposes i created this example project.